# I want a div next to an img beeing the same height, whilest using 100% of the widthof the page

Tags: html, onload

So what i was gonna, do was this:

```
<div style="">
  <img src="rootfolder_wiki/img/DeadsideGun.jpg" style="float:left; width: 50%;" id="img">
  <div style="float: left; width: 50%; background-color: red; height: 100%;" id="kaka1" onload="document.this.style.height = h;"> Hello world </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
let h = 0;
function kaka() {
  h = document.getElementById("img").height;
  h = 20;
}

kaka1.addEventListener('load', kaka());
console.log(h);
</script>
```

any help is much aprichiated, please note that i am fairly new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using float left, you might find it helpful to use flex instead.

```html
<div style="display: flex;">
  <img src="rootfolder_wiki/img/DeadsideGun.jpg" style="width: 50%;" id="img">
  <div style="background-color: red;" id="kaka1" onload="document.this.style.height = h;"> Hello world </div>
</div>
```

This will do the trick. Whist you're on the topic, I'd highly recommend learning to use flex and grid as well as CSS files. It might seem like a mouthful but it work turn out to be much easier than directly just adding style to html objects.